# Spark operator dependency issue

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, kubernetes, google-spark-operator

I am trying to run spark job using Spark operator in my kubernetes environment. All my application jar and dependencies are stored in s3. My job is running fine when i am using simple spark command. However, when I am providing below operator yaml. Job is not launching.

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: sparkapplication-25
spec:
  type: Scala
  mode: cluster
  image: "artifactory-sdf.com/spark/spark-py:v3.1.1-h3-2"
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  mainClass: com.sdf.test.SparkOperator
  mainApplicationFile: "s3a://test/jars/sparkoperatortest.jar"
  arguments:
    - "s3a://test/json/batch_job.json"
  deps:
    jars:
    - "s3a:///test/jars/dep-jar.jar" 
  sparkVersion: "3.1.1"
  restartPolicy:
    type: Never
  volumes:
    - name: "test-volume"
      hostPath:
        path: "/tmp"
        type: Directory
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: "1200m"
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.1
    serviceAccount: spark-user
    volumeMounts:
      - name: "test-volume"
        mountPath: "/tmp"
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 2
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.1
    volumeMounts:
      - name: "test-volume"
        mountPath: "/tmp"
  sparkConf:
    "spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path": "s3a://spark/jars/tmp"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key": "user"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload": "true"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key": "user@123"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint": "http://[457b:206:654e:m757:2:1:0]:32333"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access": "true"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.options.claimName": "OnDemand"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.options.storageClass": "robin"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.options.sizeLimit": "200Gi"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.mount.path": "/tmp/spark-local-dir"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.mount.readOnly": "false"
    "spark.ui.port": "4041"
```

when describing sparkapplication using below command

```
kubectl describe sparkapplications sparkapplication-25 -n spark-jobs
```

It is showing below error

```
Name:         sparkapplication-25
Namespace:    spark-jobs
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  API Version:  sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2
Kind:         SparkApplication
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-08-24T06:03:24Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:arguments:
        f:deps:
          .:
          f:jars:
        f:driver:
          .:
          f:coreLimit:
          f:cores:
          f:labels:
            .:
            f:version:
          f:memory:
          f:serviceAccount:
          f:volumeMounts:
        f:executor:
          .:
          f:cores:
          f:instances:
          f:labels:
            .:
            f:version:
          f:memory:
          f:volumeMounts:
        f:image:
        f:imagePullPolicy:
        f:mainApplicationFile:
        f:mainClass:
        f:mode:
        f:restartPolicy:
          .:
          f:type:
        f:sparkConf:
          .:
          f:spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key:
          f:spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint:
          f:spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload:
          f:spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl:
          f:spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access:
          f:spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key:
          f:spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.mount.path:
          f:spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.mount.readOnly:
          f:spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.options.claimName:
          f:spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.options.sizeLimit:
          f:spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.options.storageClass:
          f:spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path:
          f:spark.ui.port:
        f:sparkVersion:
        f:type:
        f:volumes:
    Manager:      kubectl
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2021-08-24T06:03:24Z
    API Version:  sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:applicationState:
          .:
          f:errorMessage:
          f:state:
        f:driverInfo:
        f:lastSubmissionAttemptTime:
        f:submissionAttempts:
        f:terminationTime:
    Manager:         spark-operator
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2021-08-24T06:03:27Z
  Resource Version:  155238262
  UID:               f4db9dfe-3339-4923-a771-6720ca59c511
spec:
  type: Scala
  mode: cluster
  image: "artifactory-sdf.com/spark/spark-py:v3.1.1-h3-2"
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  mainClass: com.sdf.test.SparkOperator
  mainApplicationFile: "s3a://test/jars/sparkoperatortest.jar"
  arguments:
    - "s3a://test/json/batch_job.json"
  deps:
    jars:
    - "s3a:///test/jars/dep-jar.jar" 
  sparkVersion: "3.1.1"
  restartPolicy:
    type: Never
  volumes:
    - name: "test-volume"
      hostPath:
        path: "/tmp"
        type: Directory
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: "1200m"
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.1
    serviceAccount: spark-user
    volumeMounts:
      - name: "test-volume"
        mountPath: "/tmp"
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 2
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.1
    volumeMounts:
      - name: "test-volume"
        mountPath: "/tmp"
  sparkConf:
    "spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path": "s3a://spark/jars/tmp"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key": "user"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload": "true"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key": "user@123"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint": "http://[457b:206:654e:m757:2:1:0]:32333"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access": "true"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.options.claimName": "OnDemand"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.options.storageClass": "robin"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.options.sizeLimit": "200Gi"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.mount.path": "/tmp/spark-local-dir"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.mount.readOnly": "false"
    "spark.ui.port": "4041"

Status:
  Application State:
    Error Message:  failed to run spark-submit for SparkApplication spark-jobs/sparkapplication-25: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.1.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
21/08/24 06:03:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
  at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2197)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPath(DependencyUtils.scala:191)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2(DependencyUtils.scala:147)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2$adapted(DependencyUtils.scala:145)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:145)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$4(SparkSubmit.scala:363)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1030)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
  at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
  at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
  ... 27 more

    State:  FAILED
  Driver Info:
  Last Submission Attempt Time:  2021-08-24T06:03:27Z
  Submission Attempts:           1
  Termination Time:              <nil>
Events:
  Type     Reason                            Age   From            Message
  ----     ------                            ----  ----            -------
  Normal   SparkApplicationAdded             90s   spark-operator  SparkApplication sparkapplication-25 was added, enqueuing it for submission
  Warning  SparkApplicationSubmissionFailed  87s   spark-operator  failed to submit SparkApplication sparkapplication-25: failed to run spark-submit for SparkApplication spark-jobs/sparkapplication-25: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.1.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
21/08/24 06:03:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
  at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2197)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPath(DependencyUtils.scala:191)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2(DependencyUtils.scala:147)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2$adapted(DependencyUtils.scala:145)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:145)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$4(SparkSubmit.scala:363)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
? at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1030)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
           ... 27 more
  Warning  SparkApplicationFailed  87s  spark-operator  SparkApplication sparkapplication-25 failed: failed to run spark-submit for SparkApplication spark-jobs/sparkapplication-25: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.1.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
21/08/24 06:03:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
  at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2197)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPath(DependencyUtils.scala:191)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2(DependencyUtils.scala:147)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2$adapted(DependencyUtils.scala:145)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:145)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$4(SparkSubmit.scala:363)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1030)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
  at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
  at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
  ... 27 more
```

All the hadoop-aws dependency jars are already present in our image and other jobs in which dependency jar and file is not provided are running fine even though application jar is still present in s3.

Am i missing some property here?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up solving this issue by building an image with all the necessary dependencies. Just used something like local:///path/to/jar/in/container/dep.jar

Answer (score 0):

You should add a package dependency to your config file like this:

```
deps:
  # jar dependencies
  packages:
  - org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.2
```

This would provide you the `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem` class to run your app.